# How to render a html5 and css in ionic?

Tags: ionic3

I'm have a roulette wheel open source code from github, that is build in html5, js and css. What I want it to render that in a ionic page.

That's the link :

https://github.com/zarocknz/javascript-winwheel/tree/master/examples/basic_code_wheel

How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options:

1. Create a component. Components are made of HTML, CSS(SCSS or SASS) and TYPESCRIPT. You will basically get this code in the github link and create a component on your ionic project. Since ionic is a web technology both codes will be very similar. You will have to adapt your js into ts and adapt the html to fit cellphone screens (if not already responsive).
2. Second option is to deploy the wheel externaly and use cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to open it inside the app.

Comment: The problem is that the code uses winWheel.js, which has a lot of build in function. So adapt to typescript doesn`t gonna work

Comment: Try the second option then. Deploy your wheel on another website and use cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to open this adress on your website.